# How can modify this and make use of polymorphism?

Tags: java, polymorphism, refactoring

I'm working on a Battleship project, and everything works fine. But I need to make it behave polymorphically (using polymorphism). I have the abstract class cell, and subclasses Water. 
How can achieve that? This is the portion of the code that I need to modify:

```
public void fire(char position1, char position2){
    int pos1 = (int) position1 - 64;
    int pos2 = (int) position2 - 64;

    if(pos1 > height || pos1 < 1 || pos2 > width || pos2 < 1){
        System.err.println("Illegal coordinates.");
    } else if(!(shooting_board[pos1][pos2] instanceof Water)){
        System.err.println("Coordinates previously fired upon.");

    } else if(board[pos1][pos2] instanceof Water){
        shooting_board[pos1][pos2] = new MissedMissile();
        totalMissilesFired++;
        numberOfMisses++;
        PlayBoard();
        System.out.println("Miss!");
   }else if(board[pos1][pos2] instanceof ShipSection){

       String tmp = (board[pos1][pos2].toString());
        shooting_board[pos1][pos2].damaged = true;
        shooting_board[pos1][pos2] = new ShipSection("X");
        //System.out.println(tmp);

        int tmp2 = (int)(tmp).charAt(0);
        //System.out.print(tmp2);
        tmp2 = tmp2 - 65;
        //System.out.println(tmp2);

        Ship ship = ships.get(tmp2);

        ship.hit();

        if(ship.hasSunk == true){
            sunk++;
            System.out.println("Sunk!");
            if(shipCount == sunk){
                PlayBoard();
                System.out.println("You win!");
                printStats();
                System.exit(0);
            }
       }
        totalMissilesFired++;
        numberOfHits++;
        PlayBoard();
        System.out.println("Hit!");
   }
    percentage = 100.0 * numberOfHits / totalMissilesFired;
    if (totalMissilesFired == maxMissiles){
        PlayBoard();
        System.out.println("You lose!");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you really want to refactor your code, you should start by understanding what it does, and how it does it. Then, you need to apply some object logics to it. Think what code part of your code can be reused. What functionality needs to be separated, draw an UML class diagram, etc. If you just give your code, it's like you are asking somebody to do it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anytime you see an `instanceof` check you should see if you can use polymorphism.

Instead of doing a check if `board[pos1][pos2]` *is water*, for instance, you can simply make a method in whatever type `board[pos1][pos2]` is.

Consider this method header: `void doSomething(int pos1, int pos2)`

You can then simply implement (override) it in your subclasses, for example:

```
@Override
public void doSomething(int pos1, int pos2) {
    String tmp = (board[pos1][pos2].toString());
    shooting_board[pos1][pos2].damaged = true;
    shooting_board[pos1][pos2] = new ShipSection("X");
    //System.out.println(tmp);

    int tmp2 = (int)(tmp).charAt(0);
    //System.out.print(tmp2);
    tmp2 = tmp2 - 65;
    //System.out.println(tmp2);

    Ship ship = ships.get(tmp2);

    ship.hit();

    if(ship.hasSunk == true){
        sunk++;
        System.out.println("Sunk!");
        if(shipCount == sunk){
            PlayBoard();
            System.out.println("You win!");
            printStats();
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
    totalMissilesFired++;
    numberOfHits++;
    PlayBoard();
    System.out.println("Hit!");
}
```

Then, in your main method you can simply call `doSomething` on `board[pos1][pos2]` like so: `board[pos1]][pos2].doSomething(pos1, pos2);`

Answer (score 0):

i would try something like below (but i probably have the game and player classes wrong).

```
class SO35948088 {
    static class Game {
        interface Fire {
            void fire(Game game,Player player,int x,int y);
        }
        class Player {
            void fire(int x,int y) {
                shootingBoard[x][y].fire(Game.this,this,x,y);
            }
            int totalMissilesFired;
            int numberOfMisses;
        }
        enum Type implements Fire {
            water {
                @Override public void fire(Game game,Player player,int x,int y) {
                    System.out.println("Miss!");
                }
            },
            missedMissle {
                @Override public void fire(Game game,Player player,int x,int y) {
                    // ??
                }
            },
            shipSection {
                @Override public void fire(Game game,Player player,int x,int y) {
                    System.out.println("Hit!");
                }
            }
        }
        Game(int n) {
            this.n=n;
            board=new Type[n][n];
            shootingBoard=new Type[n][n];
            for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
                for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
                    board[i][j]=shootingBoard[i][j]=Type.water;
        }
        final Player black=new Player(),white=new Player();
        final int n;
        final Type[][] board,shootingBoard;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Game game=new Game(10);
        game.shootingBoard[0][1]=Game.Type.shipSection;
        game.black.fire(0,0);
        game.white.fire(0,1);
    }
}
```